# if or case Statement in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, multi-level

I'd like some help writing or finding out if it's possible to write an if  or case statement in css for a hover function. The hover is for a dropdown  that reveals  links with shared class parent names.

The essential logic is, if one class's hover function is activated/on, deactivate/turn off the other hover function within the  that share the parent class.

in  my mind the psuedocode looks like this:

```
if (.drop: hover .last) /*when the cursor hovers, do below*/ then 

.drop: hover .last{display:block;} 

.drop:hover .first{display: none;} 

.drop:hover .second{display: none;} 

.drop:hover .third{display: none;}  
etc... 

 elseif (.drop:hover .first) then 

.drop:hover .first{display: block;} 

.drop:hover .last{display: none;} 

.drop:hover .second{display: none;}

 .drop:hover .third{display: none;} 

endif
```

Comment: well not going to happen with just CSS since there is no logic in CSS. It would help if you showed HTML Markup. Seems like simple CSS rules would be fine, but really hard to tell without the HTML.

Comment: You need JavaScript for such task.

Comment: If using javascript is not an option, you could explain exactly what you want to achieve, so we could try to find a solution. Maybe creating a codepen/plunker/jsfiddle also would help.

Comment: if and else if is similar to the way CSS works. actually it is **if the selector match  style this**, else use other or default style. :( the else if is the rule set first untill if overwrites it ... your case looks very much like : `ul ul {display:none;}  ul li:hover ul {display:block;}` . else if comes first :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you need use `:not` to ignore a `li:hover`. 
Note: use opacity instead `display: none` because the second one move the `li` to left and lost `:hover`.

Look the code below:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  display: inline-block; 
}

ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
ul:hover > li:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

more complete functionality:
https://codepen.io/ralfting/pen/qKqBvM

Comment: This is the closest that I've seen. At the time I was tasked not to used <ul> listings. They reviewed it and allowed me to use it and now that I know. I'll edit and post what I did in a codepen.

Comment: Awesome @user3444830, this approach works to me and I do not need use js to this =D

Comment: @user3444830 did you mean, you used your approach instead of mine?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I meant your approach instead of mine.

Comment: @Oh! Awesome user3444830 , mark with solved to everybody know what solution works =D Ty